Issue with .setModel() not working for 'agSetColumnFilter' in Ag-Grid
I'm encountering an issue with Ag-Grid where the .setModel() method doesn't seem to work for the agSetColumnFilter. I'm able to use .setModel() successfully with all the other provided filters from Ag-Grid, but for some reason, it's not functioning as expected with agSetColumnFilter.
even after using .setModel(), "appliedModel" property remains null.
Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Am I missing something in my implementation, or could this be a bug in Ag-Grid? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have enterprise license as well.
codes used are as shown below:

filterInstance?.setModel(filterModel);

filterInstance?.setModel({
values: filterModel.values.length>0 ? filterModel.values : []
});



One thing to verify is that onFilterChanged is getting triggered (setModel documentation):

Note that if you call setModel on the filter, you will also need to call onFilterChanged to re-run filtering, similar to Re-running Grid Filtering.

Another thing to check is that you are formatting the filter model correctly for the set filter. It uses the property "values" which should be set to an array of strings, instead of the property "filter" which would be set to a string when used by the text filter.
Also, depending on the version/API you're using, you may want to ensure that the setModel promise is resolved before calling onFilterChanged.

Yes, onFilterChanged is getting triggered; as I mentioned, setModel() is working for other filters provided by agGrid. Below is a code snippet for a better understanding of the question:
for(let key of Object.keys(this.FilterModel) ){         const filterInstance = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance(key);         const filterModel = this.FilterModel[key];         filterInstance?.setModel(filterModel);       } this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();

@AjaySingh updated with a couple of other possibilities. The async stuff may not apply in your case, but thought I'd include it. The API fluctuates a bit so there are a few different ways to go about it.
